# Material UI button missing styles after being linked

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm using a standard Material UI button that looks fine if I refresh the page that I am on.  However, if I get to the page through a link from another page (I'm using react-router-dom) then the styling from the button is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
   import {Link} from "react-router-dom"; 
                    <Link 
                          color="inherit" 
                          style={{textDecoration: 'none'}} 
                          to={link}>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                                test
                            </Button>
                    </Link>
```